# Why am I getting Attribute Error? Unable to Traceback,

Tags: python, networking, attributeerror

I am still learning Python and trying to run this Keras code in Jupyter notebook (TF 2.4.1) for triplet siamese network available in this [link](https://medium.com/@crimy/one-shot-learning-siamese-networks-and-triplet-loss-with-keras-2885ed022352). My dataset is properly loaded. But don't know why this error is coming again and again.

I am unable to trace the error. Does someone know whats wrong?

**Code:**

```
import time

dataset_train,dataset_test,x_train_origin,y_train_origin,x_test_origin,y_test_origin = buildDataSet()

network = build_network(input_shape,128)
network_train = build_model(input_shape, network, margin=0.2)
network_train.compile(loss=None, optimizer=Adam(0.0001), metrics=['accuracy'])

print("Starting training process!")
print("-------------------------------------")
t_start = time.time()
n_iter = 10


for i in range(1, n_iter+1):
    triplets = get_batch_hard(100,10,10,network)
    loss = network_train.train_on_batch(triplets, None)
    n_iteration += 1
    if i % evaluate_every == 0:
        print("\n ------------- \n")
        print("[{3}] Time for {0} iterations: {1:.1f} mins, Train Loss: {2}".format(i, (time.time()-t_start)/60.0,loss,n_iteration))
        probs,yprob = compute_probs(network,x_test_origin[:n_val,:,:,:],y_test_origin[:n_val])
```

**Error message:**

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-22-e1501b44b94a> in <module>
         17 for i in range(1, n_iter+1):
         18     triplets = get_batch_hard(100,10,10,network)
    ---> 19     loss = network_train.train_on_batch(triplets, None)
         20     n_iteration += 1
         21     if i % evaluate_every == 0:
    
    ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics, return_dict)
       1725                                                     class_weight)
       1726       self.train_function = self.make_train_function()
    -> 1727       logs = self.train_function(iterator)
       1728 
       1729     if reset_metrics:
    
    ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
        826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
        827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
    --> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
        829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
        830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    
    ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
        869       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
        870       initializers = []
    --> 871       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
        872     finally:
        873       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less
    
    ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
        724     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
        725         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    --> 726             *args, **kwds))
        727 
        728     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):
    
    ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
       2967       args, kwargs = None, None
       2968     with self._lock:
    -> 2969       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
       2970     return graph_function
       2971 
    
    ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
       3359 
       3360           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
    -> 3361           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
       3362           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
       3363 
    
    ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
       3204             arg_names=arg_names,
       3205             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
    -> 3206             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
       3207         self._function_attributes,
       3208         function_spec=self.function_spec,
    
    ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
        988         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
        989 
    --> 990       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
        991 
        992       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,
    
    ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
        632             xla_context.Exit()
        633         else:
    --> 634           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
        635         return out
        636 
    
    ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
        975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
        976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
    --> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
        978             else:
        979               raise
    
    AttributeError: in user code:
    
        C:\Users\Afaq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:805 train_function  *
            return step_function(self, iterator)
        C:\Users\Afaq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:795 step_function  **
            outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
        C:\Users\Afaq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1259 run
            return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        C:\Users\Afaq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
            return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
        C:\Users\Afaq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        C:\Users\Afaq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:788 run_step  **
            outputs = model.train_step(data)
        C:\Users\Afaq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:758 train_step
            self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
        C:\Users\Afaq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:387 update_state
            self.build(y_pred, y_true)
        C:\Users\Afaq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:318 build
            self._metrics, y_true, y_pred)
        C:\Users\Afaq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py:1163 map_structure_up_to
            **kwargs)
        C:\Users\Afaq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py:1258 map_structure_with_tuple_paths_up_to
            func(*args, **kwargs) for args in zip(flat_path_gen, *flat_value_gen)
        C:\Users\Afaq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py:1258 <listcomp>
            func(*args, **kwargs) for args in zip(flat_path_gen, *flat_value_gen)
        C:\Users\Afaq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py:1161 <lambda>
            lambda _, *values: func(*values),  # Discards the path arg.
        C:\Users\Afaq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:418 _get_metric_objects
            return [self._get_metric_object(m, y_t, y_p) for m in metrics]
        C:\Users\Afaq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:418 <listcomp>
            return [self._get_metric_object(m, y_t, y_p) for m in metrics]
        C:\Users\Afaq\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:439 _get_metric_object
            y_t_rank = len(y_t.shape.as_list())
    
        AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: Any chance you can create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? Did you try to verify that the data in `triplets` looks like it ought to (right array shape etc.)?

Comment: Thank You for your answer, I just checked by displaying triplet (images) right before this line: 'loss = network_train.train_on_batch(triplets, None)' and it is perfectly displaying mnist data.

Comment: Luckily, I traced the error, still don't know what exactly is the reason. The error was due to passing the 'None' in train_on_batch() for output 'y'. Same error occurs while using network_train.fit(). I don't know for what reason, these built-in functions are requiring input and output to be passed. I removed it by passing a dummy 'y=np.ones(batch_size)'. I hope anybody explain it better.